# Trying to choose a sample question for the tour gives an error

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, tour

Elected moderators are able to change which question is used for the tour. However, when trying to do so on RPG's tour (mostly to find out what that function actually looks like/works), it just (eventually) gives an Error page.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Be an elected moderator on a site
2. Go to `/tour`
3. Click on the "edit question" button next to the sample question. It links to `/admin/about/choose-question` which gives a error page (after a short while). Other users will see a 404 page as is expected.

Comment: No repro on gaming.se

Comment: Is this bug still present on RPG SE?

Comment: @Tsundoku Doesn't seem like it, I now get a working page. Is there a specific thing which is best to do for this Q then?